# What's a good tool to analyse assembly dependency in .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, decompiler

I know there are many tools. I want to find out a good tool to show me what assembly is missing. I encountered an exception saying that one of the dependency assembly might be missing when I tried to run a .NET app.

**UPDATE**

I want to test it on live server. Thus, ideally, I can run it without changes to the server. I can install application on the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A perfect tool for this is AsmSpy - http://mikehadlow.blogspot.nl/2011/02/asmspy-little-tool-to-help-fix-assembly.html. It shows you which assemblies your assembly is dependent upon.

Answer (score 9):

To check for runtime binding errors, one simple and efficient way is to turn on Fusion log (just change `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\ForceLog` to 1 in the registry). This will allow you to check the detailed logs on the error in the `Exception.FusionLog` property and also examine details via the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Scott Hanselman has a good [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) on the point.

Comment: Thanks! I want to test it on live server. Thus, ideally, I can run it without changes to the server. I can install application on the server.

Comment: You can set the policy with the viewer without messing with the registery

Answer (score 7):

I once used [Dependeny Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), specifically for .NET is the  [Assembly Depenency Analyser](http://drewnoakes.com/code/dependency-analyser/)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I want to test it on live server. Thus, ideally, I can run it without changes to the server. I can install application on the server.

Answer (score 3):

I would look at using the Dot Net Reflector:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector

Or Dot Peek from jet brains:

http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I want to test it on live server. Thus, ideally, I can run it without changes to the server. I can install application on the server.